# Get second segment from url

Tags: php

How to get the second segment in URL without slashes ?
For example I have a URL`s like this

```
http://foobar/first/second
```

How to get the value where "first" stands ?

Comment: for shure this is duplicate, have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: are you sure you have full url, not just request uri `/first/second`? where do you get this url?

Comment: @poelinca you didn't readthe question

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to get the path from the URL and then use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to split it into its segments:

```
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);

echo $uri_segments[0]; // for www.example.com/user/account you will get 'user'
```

Comment: For some reason I had to change this to `echo $uri_segment[1];`
Otherwise, this is the perfect solution!

Comment: This doesn't work as expected, first array value will be blank.

Comment: for mine, this works :  $segments = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/')); echo $segments;

Comment: When working outside of Wordpress [0] is the way to go but when working within I need to add [1] - interesting

Comment: Outside of WP is algo [1] the needed one.

Answer (score 19):

```
$segments = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, due to proper use of trim().

Answer (score 4):

To take your example http://domain.com/first/second

```
$segments = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));
$numSegments = count($segments); 
$currentSegment = $segments[$numSegments - 1];

echo 'Current Segment: ' , $currentSegment;
```

Would result in **Current Segment: second**

You can change the numSegments -2 to get **first**

Answer (score 3):

Here's my long-winded way of grabbing the last segment, inspired by Gumbo's answer:

```
// finds the last URL segment  
$urlArray = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $urlArray);
$numSegments = count($segments); 
$currentSegment = $segments[$numSegments - 1];
```

You could boil that down into two lines, if you like, but this way makes it pretty obvious what you're up to, even without the comment.

Once you have the `$currentSegment`, you can echo it out or use it in an if/else or switch statement to do whatever you like based on the value of the final segment.