# I want to implement this in my web page. I have only trivial knowledge in web development

Tags: php, asp.net, web, web-deployment-project

When someone loads this page,
'http://www.mydomainname.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

I want to seperate the 'abcdef......wxyz' part from the link and display it in the page.
How could i do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455531/get-second-segment-from-url) might be helpful

Comment: I'm betting that your site is not implemented in both PHP and asp.net. The answer to how to do it is going to be quite different depending on that.

Comment: Look in the `$_SERVER` supper global..  Do `print_r($_SERVER)`  specifically the `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: @Greg I don't what to start with. So i added php and asp.net in the tags.

Comment: @Tarasovych Thank you. I found a way now, the link helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like

```
$strExplode = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$strWanted = $strExplode[sizeOf($strExplode) -1];
echo $strWanted // will print 'abcdef......wxyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

You may have to do a bit of work on it though, like removing some stuff `/` But I would have to look at it to be sure.