# Get language from a url

Tags: php

I`ve got this code:

```
$actual_link = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$arr_string = explode("/",$actual_link, 3);
```

Output is:
/de/page 2...

Now how can I strip down $actual_link to only output whats between the two / (/de/, /en/)?

Thanks

Comment: can you share full url?

Comment: I edit my post.

Comment: what you are calling is fetching segments from url. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455531/get-second-segment-from-url) wil surely help you get segments from url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply split the result on `/` and get the second value.

```
$language = explode('/', $actual_link)[1];
```